# M1 Mac Snowflake connector for python - error: incompatible version of 'pyarrow' installed

Tags: python-3.x, apple-m1, pyarrow, snowflake-connector

I am getting an error message (please see screenshoot) while running in Terminal the command below:

import snowflake.connector as sf

Can someone help with this ?
Thank you.

[image: Terminal error message M1 Mac]

Answer (score 1):

The snowflake connector for python not working on Apple Silicon (M1) is a known problem.
There are some workaround available (see [here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/986))

Please find the one that worked for me below:

### Python 3.9

1. clean conda (I am using miniforge) environment (i.e., conda create -n py9 python=3.9)
2. adding dependencies via `pip` in the following order

- `pip install snowflake-sqlalchemy`
- `pip install sqlalchemy`
- `pip install snowflake-sqlalchemy`

### Python 3.10

1. clean conda environment (i.e., `conda create -n py10 python=3.10`)
2. just `pip install snowflake-sqlalchemy`

UPDATE: below the workaround endorsed by snowflake [official docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/setup.html#prerequisites) (3.8 version)

```
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n snowpark python=3.8 numpy pandas -c https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/snowflake
conda activate snowpark
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64
```